# How can I make my code below more efficient in terms of performance?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

The code below compares two arrays and checks that the elements at matching indices on both arrays have similar prime factors. If that is true, the count of matching factors ("matching") increases by 1.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const primeFactors = (n) => {
  let number = n;
  const factors = [];
  let divisor = 2;

  while (number >= 2) {
    if (number % divisor === 0) {
      factors.push(divisor);
      number /= divisor;
    } else {
      divisor += 1;
    }
  }
  return factors;
};

const solution = (A, B) => {
  let matching = 0;

  for (let index = 0; index < A.length; index += 1) {
    const a = A[index];
    const b = B[index];

    let aFactors = primeFactors(a);
    aFactors = new Set(aFactors);
    aFactors = Array.from(aFactors);
    aFactors = aFactors.sort((first, second) => first - second);
    let bFactors = primeFactors(b);
    bFactors = new Set(bFactors);
    bFactors = Array.from(bFactors);
    bFactors = bFactors.sort((first, second) => first - second);

    if (JSON.stringify(aFactors) === JSON.stringify(bFactors)) {
      matching += 1;
    }
  }
  return matching;
};
```

This will return 1 since only 15 and 75 at matching indices have similar prime factors (3 and 5 each)

```
console.log(solution([15, 10, 3], [75, 30, 5]));
```

How can I make this algorithm more efficient? It currently has an efficiency score of 84%, having failed two optimization tests for large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

1. Converting an array to a set and back to an array seems like much of a wasted effort. Why not eliminate duplicates right in `primeFactors`?

   ```
    while (number >= 2) {
        if (number % divisor === 0) {
            factors.push(divisor);
            while (number % divisor === 0) {
                number /= divisor;
            }
        } else {
            divisor += 1;
        }
    }
   ```
2. There is no need to sort the arrays obtained as above. They are already sorted. There is also no need to stringify them. Just compare them element by element.
3. The fundamental speedup comes from the observation that the two numbers have the same prime composition *if and only if* they have the same prime compositions with their `gcd`. The `gcd` is very easy to compute; it also tends to be much smaller, and hence much easier to decompose, than its arguments. Besides, it requires only one decomposition, rather than two as in your solution. Consider

   ```
    same_prime_composition(a, b)
        g = gcd(a, b)
        primes = primeFactors(g)
        return is_decomposable(a/g, primes) && is_decomposable(b/g, primes)

    prime_decomposable(x, primes)
        for p in primes
            while (x % p == 0)
                x /= p
        return x === 1
   ```
4. It might be beneficial to compute the prime numbers beforehand.
5. I don't know if [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) supports `divmod`. If it does, there is even more room for optimization.

Comment: Great recommendation here. The third recommendation and the code snippet are not so clear to me though. Kindly expound.

Answer (score 0):

A quick speedup is to have PrimeFactors stop at sqrt(n).  The value of `number` at that time is necessarily the last prime factor.